# Google Chart How can I pass variables to a DataView calculated column function?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

According to Google a DataView can be used to calculated column values on the fly.
([see documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns))

```
var myValue = 100;

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    
view.setColumns([
  data.getColumnIndex('PART'),
  data.getColumnIndex('VALUE'), 
  { calc:  exampleFromGoogle, type: 'number'},
  { calc:  customWithExternalValues, type: 'number'},
]);
```

The google calc example does not do not use any outside values and is self contained.

```
function exampleFromGoogle(dataTable, rowNum) {     
    return Math.floor(dataTable.getValue(rowNum, 1) / 2.54);
}
```

I would like to pass the calc function a variable `myValue` but I do not know the syntax where the calculation function is called. `{ calc:  customWithExternalValues, type: 'number'}`

This is the function I wish to use.

```
function customWithExternalValues(dataTable, rowNum, myValue) { 
    return (Math.floor(dataTable.getValue(rowNum, 1) / 2.54))* myValue;
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated...Thanks!

Comment: not following exactly, where is the value for `myValue` going to be set...?

Comment: I added `var myValue = 100;` declaration above.  The idea is that a variable value is calculated externally and then passed into the function.  But I don't know how to pass `myValue` into `{ calc:  customWithExternalValues, type: 'number'},`  Google only gives the self contained example `exampleFromGoogle` which has all the values it needs to return a value.  Does this clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the custom function within the example function...

```
var myValue = 100;

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

view.setColumns([
  data.getColumnIndex('PART'),
  data.getColumnIndex('VALUE'), 
  { calc:  exampleFromGoogle, type: 'number'},
  { calc:  exampleFromGoogle, type: 'number'},
]);

function exampleFromGoogle(dataTable, rowNum) {
    return customWithExternalValues(dataTable, rowNum, myValue);
}

function customWithExternalValues(dataTable, rowNum, myValue) {
    return (Math.floor(dataTable.getValue(rowNum, 1) / 2.54)) * myValue;
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Home run once again...Thank you so much!!